# Spliting dataset into train and test which got from two different data source and make sure that split dataset contain entries from both the sources

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn

I have data set which i got from two different sources. I merged them and make final data set. I am applying k-fold cross validation and want to make sure that for train-test split of each fold should content entries from both the sources. Following is example code:

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, StratifiedKFold
import numpy as np
datasource1=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
datasource1_label=np.array([0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0])#0 for odd and 1 for even
datasource2=np.array([12,13,14,15])
datasource2_label=np.array([1,0,1,0])#0 for odd and 1 for even
merge_data=np.concatenate((datasource1,datasource2))
merge_label=np.concatenate((datasource1_label, datasource2_label))
x,y = shuffle(merge_data,merge_label)

kf = KFold(n_splits=3,shuffle=False)
kf.get_n_splits()
train_index_list=[];test_index_list=[]
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(x,y):
    x_train, x_test = x[train_index], x[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    train_index_list.append(train_index)
    test_index_list.append(test_index)
```

I am not mentioning random_state for shuffle and kfold, because i have tried different experiments. `n_split` cab be any vlaue like 5 fold or 10 fold. sometimes it may happen that any one (or more than one) fold doesn't content any value from second dataset or similar for test data.

Comment: I have just given a simple example, when we increase data there is and also length of data source differ by large amount, then there is chances that above mention thing can happen

Comment: Split two datasets independently and then join the train sets together and test sets together

Comment: I thought the same, but is there any other way to do the same.

Comment: Nope. I dont think so. You can try merging them and then split as you are trying now, but that would require keeping some information about the datasets and using them as groups. So I would prefer first splitting and then joining.

Comment: I second Vivek Kumar's comment. Best is to split independently and then merge. One addition, if you want to add some randomness : when you merge them, you can have a random number deciding how many elements from one or the other subsets you take. Something like if np.random()>alpha draw from subset 1, else draw from subset 2, where alpha is the data imbalance between the two datasets.

Comment: @Ben may you please give a small example with the help of code about how to use `np.random()>alpha`

Comment: Hi, here is a gist. I only implemented the data and not the labels, but it's the same idea : https://gist.github.com/benoitrosa/70f5369feaad62be2fc5c5447066f3d0

Now that I coded it I'm not sure it is of much value w.r.t simply making a kfold on each dataset and merging the folds. But you get the idea if you need it, at least.

Comment: thnx, but with labels it will be more useful